# RabbitMQ - connect using AMQP and STOMP to same exchange

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

We are using RabbitMQ as message broker. Producer1 connects using AMQP, Producer2 connects using STOMP protocol, Consumer1 connects using AMQP, Consumer2 (using javascript) connects using STOMP via websocket.
(Producer1 and consumer1 uses spring cloud stream)

Test1: When producer1 using AMQP sends messages, it is received in consumer1(AMQP) and failed to receive in consumer2(STOMP). Consumer2 javascript client is getting disconnected immediately when producer1(AMQP) send message and queue is getting deleted.

Test2: When producer2 using STOMP sends message, it is received in consumer1(AMQP) and consumer 2 (STOMP) with out any issue.

Test1 -  is it possible scenario? We are trying to connect to same exchange in RabbitMQ using AMQP and STOMP protocol by consumers. STOMP consumer is being disconnected when AMQP producer sends message. Verified both rabbitmq and consumer logs. it didn't give much information in logs.

Comment: What kind of data are you sending; IIRC STOMP only supports text.

Comment: Message is of type UTF-8. This should be causing the issue. ( I am using avro for serialization with spring cloud stream producer (AMQP)). Is there any approach we can follow to use AMQP (spring cloud stream) and STOMP (websocket server)  for communication using rabbit MQ as message broker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As STOMP only supports text. Changing the message content type worked.